# Acceder a un objeto jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, poo

Hola tengo el siguente objecto que contiene otros objectos y me gustaria acceder a las propiedades de cada pero cada vez que hago console.log de una de estas me sale undefined

```
$.each(response.data, function (index, value){
    console.log(value);
    $.each(value, function (index, valor){
         console.log(valor);
         console.log(valor.id); // DEVUELVE UNDEFINED
    })
})
```

Si hago console.log(valor):
[image: console.log(valor)]

Si hago console.log(valor.id):
[image: console.log(valor.id)]

Comment: Una muestra de los datos para poder componer un ejemplo nos ayudaría mucho para poder ayudarte, te recomiendo leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: Si lo que estás buscando es obtener el nombre de la propiedad, intenta haciendo `console.log(index);` en lugar de `console.log(valor.id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo correcto seria:

```
var data = response.data;
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    console.log(val.id)
})
```

El segundo `.each` es innecesario